# Generate Swagger documentation as JSON/YAML in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, nestjs

I've followed the [instructions to create a Swagger documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger), and my documentation is now available using Swagger UI. I'd like to also generate the documentation as JSON or YAML so it's easy to import in e.g. Postman, but I can't find any suitable methods in the `SwaggerModule`, nor does the Swagger UI have any export button.

Comment: Yeah I've been wondering about this too, NestJS can be a bit obfuse

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/57#issuecomment-368238060) you can just stringify the created Swagger `document` and e.g. write it to the file system like this:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setDescription("description")
    .setVersion("1.0")
    .build();
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);

fs.writeFileSync("./swagger-spec.json", JSON.stringify(document));
SwaggerModule.setup("/api", app, document);

await app.listen(80);
```

Comment: This worked very well for me, I added an if condition to save that file only on development environment: `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')`

Comment: Is there a way to import this to Postmann as an Collection ?

Comment: A note on importing fs/path module(s) if you get an error try importing like this. 
import * as fs from fs
import * as path from path

Comment: This works - but if all you want to do is export the file as a cli task, without starting the server, my workaround is to create a new nest config, and use the `--config` flag of `nest start` and specify the `entryFile` parameter to be a new `swagger-main.ts` where you don't specify `app.listen`. Alternatively you can try `nest-commander` package.

Answer (score 22):

Tested in **Nestjs v9**

Suppose the docs path is as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/docs
```

Get JSON

```
http://localhost:3000/docs-json
```

Get YAML

```
http://localhost:3000/docs-yaml
```

Comment: http://localhost:3000/docs-json works ok. http://localhost:3000/docs-yaml not found.

Comment: I just tried and both routes worked for me. Make sure you are using the latest version of Nestjs (10 for core and 7 for swagger)

Answer (score 12):

Try visiting `/api/json` instead of `/api-json` if you followed *https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger*.

Comment: in my case I use `SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document)`, so I download json file from _localhost:3000/docs-json_

Comment: Are you sure about that?  It seems the linked webpage references `/api-json`.

Comment: above comment is incorrect, directly from the linked doc as of April, 2023: To generate and download a Swagger JSON file, navigate to `http://localhost:3000/api-json` (assuming that your Swagger documentation is available under `http://localhost:3000/api`).

Answer (score 1):

As well as the solution shown to write to disk (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51736406/5693245), you can still access on your own API endpoint.

As per [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction), depending on whether you use `swagger-ui-express` or `fastify` to serve docs the location will be different

> To generate and download a Swagger JSON file, navigate to http://localhost:3000/api-json (swagger-ui-express) or http://localhost:3000/api/json (fastify-swagger) in your browser (assuming that your Swagger documentation is available under http://localhost:3000/api).

It also depends on where you serve your API from, and assumes you use `/api`. If this is not the case replace with your endpoint, or in case you are not using a base URL for `swagger-ui-express` this would be http://localhost:3000/-json

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Nestjs v8

```
GET http://{host}:{port}/docs
```

Get JSON

```
GET http://{host}:{port}/docs/json
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version (v8 as of writing) of NestJS, following the setup in the [openapi documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction), you should be able to access the json document without any extra setup with

```
GET http://{host}:{port}/api-docs
```

Answer (score 0):

I need generate open API json file without database, webserver etc. dependency that's my app has. So I wrote another main.ts file (actualy I named it main-generate-swagger.ts).  **This main-generate-swagger.ts file is for json file generation only**. No run it on production!

main-generate-swagger.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
    
async function bootstrap() {
   const app = await NestFactory.create(
      AppModule,
      { preview: true, abortOnError: false } // <-- This parameters prevent for instantiate controllers but its not necessary for SwaggerModule
   );
    
    const prefix = 'api/v1';
    const corsOrigin = '*';
    
    app.enableCors({ origin: corsOrigin });
    app.setGlobalPrefix(prefix);
    
    const config = new DocumentBuilder().setTitle('Title').setDescription('Description').setVersion('1.0').addBearerAuth().build();
    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
    
    await fs.writeFile('path/to/create/swagger.json', JSON.stringify(document));
    process.exit();
}
    
bootstrap();
```

Now instead of running main.ts file I run my new main-generate-swagger.ts. It generates json file and quit.

Notes:

- How to configure app to start with main-generate-swagger.ts instead main.ts depends on environment. I use nx.dev so I change it in project.json.