# NestJS - Swagger JSON Export

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I have Swagger, which works just fine. But I cant find a way to export the routes to JSON.
I remember of doing this, just by visiting a URL in the browser, but I can't remember it now.

My swagger is setup like this:

```
const swaggerOptions = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Some API Docs')
    .setDescription('Some API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .build();

  const swaggerDocument = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, swaggerOptions);
  SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, swaggerDocument);
```

And I can access the Swagger UI using:
localhost:3000/docs

I have read the [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction), and they mention to use:

- http://localhost:3000/api/json or http://localhost:3000/api-json

Also, I looked on SO, and there is this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732236/generate-swagger-documentation-as-json-yaml-in-nestjs)

Unfortunately, none of it works in my case.

What is the URL to get the documentation in JSON?

Comment: See [How to export a Swagger JSON/YAML file from Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your SwaggerModule configuration the URL for JSON should be at `/docs-json`.

The official documentation mentions `api-json` because they register using `api` as the first param